# Displaying only a person's highest score from a .txt file (Python 3)

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to learn the fundamentals of using Python for a personal project.

I have created a program which asks the user ten geographical questions, and then saves their score to a .txt file, in this format:

```
Imran - 8
Joeseph - 5
Test1 - 6
Test2 - 4
Joeseph - 10
Aaron - 4
Test1 - 1
Zzron - 1
Joeseph - 3
Test1 - 10
Joeseph - 4
```

I am now attempting to make another program which reads through this .txt file, and displays the highest score of each person in alphabetical order, like this:

```
Aaron - 4
Imran - 8
Joeseph - 10
Test1 - 10
Test1 - 6
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1
```

I have currently, I have been able to organize the user's scores in alphabetical order, but how do I alter the code such that only a person's highest score is displayed?:

```
with open("highscores.txt", "r+")as file:
    file.seek(0)
    scores = file.readlines()

alphabetical = []
for i in range (0, len(scores)):
    line = scores[i].rstrip('\n')
    alphabetical.append(line)

alphabetical = sorted(alphabetical)
for i in range (0, len(alphabetical)):
    print (alphabetical[i])
```

Comment: While reading each line, split it using ' - ' as a separator. Convert the score to an integer and create a tuple containing the name and score. Append that tuple to a list. Once your list is ready referer to http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577535-aggregates-using-groupby-defaultdict-and-counter/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying only the highest of a person's 3 most recent scores, saved in a .txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785780/displaying-only-the-highest-of-a-persons-3-most-recent-scores-saved-in-a-txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a dictionary to store your scores; store the name and score separately (with scores converted to an integer), replacing the score only if it is higher:

```
user_scores = {}
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
        user_scores[name] = score
```

Once you have your dictionary built up, you can sort the keys (the names) and display each name with that score:

```
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
```

Demo:

```
>>> scores = '''\
... Imran - 8
... Joeseph - 5
... Test1 - 6
... Test2 - 4
... Joeseph - 10
... Aaron - 4
... Test1 - 1
... Zzron - 1
... Joeseph - 3
... Test1 - 10
... Joeseph - 4
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> user_scores = {}
>>> for line in scores:
...     name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
...     score = int(score)
...     if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
...         user_scores[name] = score
... 
>>> for name in sorted(user_scores):
...     print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
... 
Aaron - 4
Imran - 8
Joeseph - 10
Test1 - 10
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open ("input.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

rows = data.split("\n")
people = {}
for row in rows:
  tmp = row.split(" - ")
  if len(tmp) < 2: continue
  if tmp[0] not in people: people[tmp[0]] = []
  people[tmp[0]].append(int(tmp[1]))

for person in people:
  print person, max(people[person])
```