# Displaying only the highest of a person's 3 most recent scores, saved in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn the fundamentals of using Python for a personal project.

I have created a program which asks the user ten geographical questions, and then saves their score to a .txt file, in this format:

```
Imran - 8
Joeseph - 10
Test1 - 6
Test2 - 4
Joeseph - 5
Aaron - 4
Test1 - 1
Zzron - 1
Joeseph - 3
Test1 - 10
Joeseph - 4
```

I then created a new program, which can be used to display the highest score of each person in alphabetical order:

```
with open("highscores.txt", "r+")as file:
    file.seek(0)
    scores = file.readlines()

user_scores = {}
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
        user_scores[name] = score

for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
```

I would like to alter this code, such that it only outputs the highest of a person's 3 most recent scores. For example, from the .txt file given, Joeseph's score would be displayed as:

```
Joeseph - 5
```

The program should omit all but the 3 most recent scores from each person.

Comment: Lol @ *"a personal project"*. Yeah, nobody will see through this ingenious ruse.

Comment: You neglected to ask a question, and the implied one is too broad.  Get a piece of lined paper; make marks on the paper while you scan the data.; then mark the answer.  Once you can do that, modify your code to do the same thing (its outline is correct).  If you then have a specific problem, edit your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To prevent having your post closed, please make it clear what you are asking, what you have tried, and where you are still having issues. The site is not for code review. If the question is related to homework, please use the "homework" tag. Rest of you guys should mind your manners with new users.

Comment: @Benjamin There is no homework tag, and [there has no been one for a long time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/254929).

Comment: @Air I guess it's been a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of the highest score in your first for loop, just keep track of the last three scores:

```
user_scores = {}
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        user_scores[name] = []       # Initialize score list
    user_scores[name].append(score)  # Add the most recent score
    if len(user_scores[name]) > 3:   
        user_scores[name].pop(0)     # If we've stored more than 3, get rid of the oldest
```

Then at the end, go through and get the maximum:

```
user_high_scores = {}
for name in user_scores:
    user_high_scores[name] = max(user_scores[name])   # Find the highest of the 3 most recent scores
```

Then you can print out the high scores as before:

```
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the deque advice, I've added that to my answer. (I'm not the author of the answer you commented on, I just wanted to thank you for the help.)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque    
with open("highscores.txt", "r+")as file:
    file.seek(0)
    scores = file.readlines()
user_scores = defaultdict(lambda:deque(maxlen=3))
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    user_scores[name].append(score)
for name in user_scores:
    print(name, '-', max(user_scores[name]))
```

By using defaultdict, we avoid ugly in checking. The deque keeps only the last 3 scores. Note this works even if the user has less than 3 scores.

If you need the high scores sorted, than the last loop can be replaced with:

```
user_scores=[(max(user_scores[user]), user) for user in user_scores]
for score, name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', score)
```

Comment: Having answered a bit late, I think the use of the queue is better than my suggestion. I didn't even think of that. That plus the optional loop statement should probably be the cleanest version so far I think.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you only want to read the last 3 scores, start from the end of the file and read backwards.

```
user_scores = {}
for line in reversed(open("scores.txt").readlines()):
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    # first, only update if the name exists 
    # and there is less than 3 scores already
    if name in user_scores and len(user_scores[name]) < 3:
        user_scores[name].append(score)
    # this is a new record, so lets just add it
    # make the value a list so we can easily just add a score to it
    if name not in user_scores:
        user_scores[name] = list((score,))
```

now we have a dict of users each with a list of the 3 most recent scores. Lets get their top scores.

```
best_scores = {}
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    # get the highest score in the list.
    best_scores[name] = max(user_scores[name])
```

now, we can simply print out the user's highest scores as needed

```
for name in sorted(best_scores):
    print("{} - {}".format(name, best_scores[name]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the output should be:

```
Joeseph - 5
Joeseph - 3
Joeseph - 4
```

This is how I would solve the problem

```
with open("highscores.txt", "r+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    scores = file.readlines()

# generate list of [name, score] pairs instead of strings
scores_pairs = [score.strip().split(' - ') for score in scores]

# configure output
lookup_name = 'Joeseph'
RECENT_SCORES_LIMIT = 3

# indicates how many scores were added
recent_scores_count = 0
# scores will be stored here
most_recent_scores = []

# we need to reverse list to search it from the end
for score in reversed(scores_pairs):
    name = score[0]
    # if current score is if interested person and scores limit not exceeded...
    if name == lookup_name and recent_scores_count < RECENT_SCORES_LIMIT:
        # add current score to list
        most_recent_scores.append(score)
        recent_scores_count += 1

# to display scores in historical order we need to reverse list again
for name, score in reversed(most_recent_scores):
    # better use .format method to produce strings using python variables
    print('{} - {}'.format(name, score))
```

Answer (score -1):

The usual way to do this is using `collections.deque`

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

d = defaultdict(lambda: deque(maxlen=3))
# some dict d where d['new key'] -> d['new key'] = deque(maxlen=3)

with open('path/to/scores.txt') as scores:
    for line in scores:
        name, score = line.split(" - ")
        d[name].append(int(score))

for player, scores in sorted(d.items()):
    print("{} - {}".format(player, max(scores))
    # {"James":deque([2,6,11]), -> "James - 11"
    # {"Susan":deque([3,1,2])}  -> "Susan - 3"
```