# How to store last three scores

Tags: python, csv, text

I have been doing a school project recently which which is about a school maths quiz. I successfully done two of the three tasks of my project. However the third task is seeming quite difficult.

I'm currently trying to store the last three scores of that student. However I can't quite get it to work. I did have a look at this thread: [Displaying only the highest of a person's 3 most recent scores, saved in a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785780/displaying-only-the-highest-of-a-persons-3-most-recent-scores-saved-in-a-txt). However I am having an error in my code for the for:

```
scores = file.readlines()
```

Which gives me an error saying that it's not readable. So unfortunately I couldn't get that code to work.

So what I'm trying to do is score the last three scores of the student. Then if there is more then 3, then I want to delete the least recent score.

This is my code:

```
import random
import csv
import operator
import os.path
import sys

user_scores = {}

validclass = "No"
classfile = "Class"
studentteacher = "None"

while studentteacher == "None":
    studentteacherinput = input("Are you a Teacher or a Student?")

if studentteacherinput == "Teacher":
        studentteacher = "Teacher"
        print(studentteacher)
    elif studentteacherinput == "Student":
        studentteacher = "Student"
        print(studentteacher)
    else:
        print("Please enter the one applicable ' Student ' or ' Teacher '.")

while validclass == "No":

    pupilclass = input("What class are you in or what class would you like to see??")
    print(pupilclass)

    if pupilclass == "1":
        if os.path.exists("class1scores.txt") and studentteacher == "Teacher":
            file = open("class1scores.txt", "r")
            validclass = "Yes"
        elif os.path.exists("class1scores.txt") and studentteacher == "Student":
            file = open("class1scores.txt", "a")
            classfile = "class1scores.txt"
            validclass = "Yes"
        else:
            file = open("class1scores.txt", "w")
            validclass = "Yes"

    elif pupilclass == "2":
        if os.path.exists("class2scores.txt") and studentteacher == "Teacher":
            file = open("class2scores.txt", "r")
            validclass = "Yes"
        elif os.path.exists("class2scores.txt") and studentteacher == "Student":
            file = open("class2scores.txt", "a")
            classfile = "class2scores.txt"
            validclass = "Yes"
        else:
            file = open("class1scores.txt", "w")
            validclass = "Yes"

    elif pupilclass == "3":
        if os.path.exists("class3scores.txt") and studentteacher == "Teacher":
            file = open("class3scores.txt", "r")
            validclass = "Yes"
        elif os.path.exists("class3scores.txt") and studentteacher == "Student":
            file = open("class3scores.txt", "a")
            classfile = "class3scores.txt"
            validclass = "Yes"
        else:
            file = open("class1scores.txt", "w")
            validclass = "Yes"

file.seek(0)
scores = file.readline()

if studentteacher == "Teacher":
    teacherinput = input("How would you like to sort the list? ' Alphabetically ' to sort it alphabetically with the students highest score, ' Highest ' for the highest scores with highest to lowest or ' Average ' for average scores with highest to lowest")

    if teacherinput == "Alphabetically":
        print("alphabetically")
        csv1 = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ",")
        sort = sorted(csv1, key = operator.itemgetter(0))

        for eachline in sort:
            print(eachline)

        sys.exit()

    if teacherinput == "Highest":
        print("Highest")

    if teacherinput == "Average":
        print("Average")

namecheck = "invalid"

while namecheck == "invalid":
    name = input("Please enter your name?")
    if name.isalpha():
        print("Your name is valid.")
        namecheck = "valid"
        #file.write(name + ",")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid name, only containing letters.")

operation = input("Hello %s! Would you like to do Addition, Subtraction or Multiplication" % (name))

score = 0

if operation == "Addition":
    for i in range(0, 10):
        number1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        number2 = random.randint(1, 20)
        answer = number1 + number2
        question = input("What is " + str(number1) + " + " + str(number2))

        if question.isdigit() == True:
            int(question)
        else:
            question = input("Please enter a answer with digits only. What is " + str(number1) + " + " + str(number2))

        if int(question) == answer:
            score += 1
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Wrong!")

elif operation == "Subtraction":
    for i in range(0, 10):
        number1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        number2 = random.randint(1, 20)
        answer = number1 - number2
        if number2 >= number1:
            answer = number2 - number1
            question = input("What is " + str(number2) + " - " + str(number1))
        else:
            question = input("What is " + str(number1) + " - " + str(number2))

        if question.isdigit() == True:
            int(question)
        else:
            if number2 >= number1:
                answer = number2 - number1
                question = input("Please enter a positive answer with digits only. What is " + str(number2) + " - " + str(number1))
            else:
                question = input("Please enter a positive answer with digits only. What is " + str(number1) + " - " + str(number2))

        if int(question) == answer:
            score += 1
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Wrong!")

elif operation == "Multiplication":
    for i in range(0, 10):
        number1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        number2 = random.randint(1, 20)
        answer = number1 * number2
        question = input("What is " + str(number1) + " x " + str(number2))

        if question.isdigit() == True:
            int(question)
        else:
            question = input("Please enter a answer with digits only. What is " + str(number1) + " + " + str(number2))

        if int(question) == answer:
            score += 1
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Wrong!")



print("Your final score is %s/10, Well Done!" % (score))
#file.write(str(score) + "\n")

#This is the code which I was trying to use to get the last 3 scores.
user_scores = {}
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        user_scores[name] = []       # Initialize score list
    user_scores[name].append(score)  # Add the most recent score
    if len(user_scores[name]) > 3:
        user_scores[name].pop(0)     # If we've stored more than 3, get rid of the oldest

file.close()
```

Sorry for the inefficient method, but it's just the way I like to think. And thanks for your time.

```
#This is the code which I was trying to use to get the last 3 scores.
user_scores = {}
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        user_scores[name] = []       # Initialize score list
    user_scores[name].append(score)  # Add the most recent score
    if len(user_scores[name]) > 3:
        user_scores[name].pop(0)     # If we've stored more than 3, get rid of the oldest
```

So I took that from the link mentioned above. My aim is to try and only get three scores, and not above 3.

Comment: Can you reduce your code example to something that only highlights the problem? Check out [how to write a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you by any chance giving the options (when asked for all those inputs) that would lead to one of the `file = open(somefile, 'w')` lines? You cannot read from a file that is opened just for writing.

Comment: Also you can't read from a file if the file's permissions does not allow it for the OTHERS group. When I was at school my teachers gave us some files with these properties locked.

Comment: You should really learn about functions... Your code might be more or less kind-of "working", but it's a big ball of mudd.

Comment: @OliverW. I am giving the options when it asks for what class you're in.

Comment: @OliverW. I edited the post adding a section focusing on the area I want to try and get working. So I've basically moved my file writing for the name and score to the bottom. But that error I'm having won't allow me to use the scores = file.readlines()

Comment: That error comes from trying to execute the `readline()` method on a file that wasn't opened for *reading*. I am still making a (fairly educated) guess here, but you are probably feeding your script that you're a "Student", in which case you end up in an `open(..., 'a')` case. Then calling `readline` will fail. Try it.

Comment: @OliverW. Thanks for that, it solved one problem. So what I done was moved the scores = file.readlines() to the reading section within the options. Now when I try and use the code as a Student, it gives me the error that scores can not be found. I realize that this is because I'm not assigning it because that code is for a Teacher. However is there an alternative or a better piece of code for it?

Comment: @Osman, I should have posted it as an answer then. Someone else did now, which is my loss. So technically, your first question is answered and you should refrain from editing a post or adding comments to it, as it will make some of the answers and comments seem completely out of place. You should ask a new question. However, rather than doing that immediately, bruno gave a good comment about using functions. You should look into that as it will greatly simplify your code: it's a better fit for it. Also check out [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a queue - https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

```
from collections import deque

for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        user_scores[name] = deque(maxlen=3)
    temp_q = user_scores[name]
    temp_q.append(str(score))
    user_scores[name] = temp_q
```

Now user scores is a dict with key as name, and values as a deque object with just 3 scores. You need to iterate through them, cast the queue to list and join the elements to write them to file.

```
filehandle = open('outputfile.csv' ,'w')
for key, values in user_scores.iteritems():
    filehandle.write(name + ',')
    filehandle.write(','.join(list(values)) + '\n')

filehandle.close()
```

Comment: So I added this code, and I'm getting this error: file.write(str(score) + "\n") I have these two in my code: file.write(name + ",") and file.write(str(score) + "\n") before the code. @Rcynic

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the full picture - which should address the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for that @Rcynic. I just needed to change one part which was .iteritems() as it's not supported in Python 3 anymore. I removed the iter to make it .items() and it worked. Found this out from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444340/iter-values-item-in-dictionary-does-not-work.

Comment: I get this error: name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack @Rcynic

Comment: Check your input file - maybe you have more columns?

Comment: I think I made a mistake by not closing the file. But when I run that code, what happens is that a new line is made within the CSV file. How would I go about checking if name is in user_scores?

Comment: `print user_scores["name that should be here"]` or if you want to see all the keys in the dict `print user_scores.keys()`

Comment: How would I read the CSV and put it into a dictionary? @Rcynic

Comment: use the csv module [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that should open give you cell level access in the csv. How exactly to fill the user scores dict will depend on the structure of your csv file itself.

Comment: Okay @Rcynic will have a look at that. Do you know why the code is making a new row in the CSV every time the code is ran? Shouldn't it append to the row for that name?

Comment: The code should write the name and 3 scores in the same line and then any other name will be in a new line. Unless you have multiple files with different scores for the same people. Build the `user_scores` dict on all files first and then write out to csv.

Comment: thank you for your help man, just one thing I would suggest is to use key when writing to the file rather than name. When I had name there it caused all the different names (i.e. Osman, Jack, Adnan) to all become the name that was inputted when that code was ran.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to know, there are different modes you can `open()`([2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)/[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)) a file in. If you use `"a"` or `"w"`, you can't read from the file. You can add a `"+"`, to allow reading, too, though:

```
open("file.txt","a+")
```

Also, I'm not sure what version of Python you're using, but [`file()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is a built-in type and function in Python 2, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name if that's the version you're using.